# System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized Error is coming

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My Gridview was working fine when I did not defined the `Usertype` for the logg in users. Now my `BindGrid()` function is not working properly and giving me error as

*System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized Error is coming*

Here is my BindGrid code behind:-

```
protected void BindGrid()
    {
        string username = string.Empty;
        string usertype = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT usertype,username FROM tbl_User WHERE username='" + Session["User"].ToString() + "'", conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    username = dr["username"].ToString();
                    usertype = dr["usertype"].ToString();
                }
            }
            conn.Close();

            string query = string.Empty;

            if (usertype == "0") // superadmin
            {
                query = "select Id,username,email,usertype,active,(CASE WHEN usertype='1' THEN 'Admin' WHEN usertype='0' THEN 'Super Admin' WHEN usertype='2' THEN 'User' END) AS UserRoleName from tbl_User ORDER By Id DESC";
            }
            if (usertype == "1") // admin
            {
                query = "select Id,username,email,usertype,active,(CASE WHEN usertype='1' THEN 'Admin' WHEN usertype='0' THEN 'Super Admin' WHEN usertype='2' THEN 'User' END) AS UserRoleName from tbl_User WHERE usertype != '0' ORDER By Id DESC";
            }
            if (usertype == "2") // user
            {
                query = "select Id,username,email,usertype,active,(CASE WHEN usertype='1' THEN 'Admin' WHEN usertype='0' THEN 'Super Admin' WHEN usertype='2' THEN 'User' END) AS UserRoleName from tbl_User WHERE username='" + username + "' ORDER By Id DESC";
            }

            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            grdUser.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            grdUser.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Please suggest what is wrong here.

Comment: What? Your user name is `Robert'); DROP TABLE tbl_User;--` ... seriously?

Comment: @AaronPalmer: Yes I have table with name `tbl_user` what is the matter ?

Comment: I think @AaronPalmer means that your code is unsafe :) and is bound to sql injection..

Comment: Your conn is closed and migt be empty if you run the second sqlcommand and read-up on [sql injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Use [SqlCommandParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am joking with a bit of warning as well.  Please refer to http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @GregOks: Can you suggest better way,please.

Comment: Yes, you use parameterized SQL. Always, always, always.

Comment: But it looks like your exception is actually coming from the second query, where you're using `cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);`. Have you logged `query` in that case? (Switch statements are good for limited options, too...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I want to check the `usertype` and according to that basis it should display the data in the grid. Also any sugesstion of `parameterized SQL`

Comment: Hi, check whether you are getting the query value or not. I think the query variable is NULL

Comment: @LokeshBR: My last query is not working in the SQL, i entered username as `Nadeem` for testing

Comment: What happens if usertype is not 0,1 or 2?

Comment: @rene: If Usertype is 0= Super Admin, 1= Admin and 2= Users

Comment: @NadeemKhan - research the following: `using` statement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: That is not what I'm asking...

Comment: @AaronPalmer: Thanks, will implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have add the paramaters and its safe to use now.

```
protected void BindGrid()
        {
            string username = string.Empty;
            string usertype = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT usertype,username FROM tbl_User WHERE username=@username", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session["User"].ToString();

                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        username = dr["username"].ToString();
                        usertype = dr["usertype"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();

                string query = string.Empty;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usertype))
                {
                    if (usertype == "0") // superadmin
                    {
                        query = "select Id,username,email,usertype,active,(CASE WHEN usertype='1' THEN 'Admin' WHEN usertype='0' THEN 'Super Admin' WHEN usertype='2' THEN 'User' END) AS UserRoleName from tbl_User ORDER By Id DESC";
                    }
                    if (usertype == "1") // admin
                    {
                        query = "select Id,username,email,usertype,active,(CASE WHEN usertype='1' THEN 'Admin' WHEN usertype='0' THEN 'Super Admin' WHEN usertype='2' THEN 'User' END) AS UserRoleName from tbl_User WHERE usertype != '0' ORDER By Id DESC";
                    }
                    if (usertype == "2") // user
                    {
                        query = "select Id,username,email,usertype,active,(CASE WHEN usertype='1' THEN 'Admin' WHEN usertype='0' THEN 'Super Admin' WHEN usertype='2' THEN 'User' END) AS UserRoleName from tbl_User WHERE username='" + username + "' ORDER By Id DESC";
                    }

                    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    grdUser.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    grdUser.DataBind();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The grid is binded properly now, but when i move forward to check the next page, i get same error. and that goes in `catch`

Comment: move forward to next page?

Comment: Not next page, i mean - next page of the gridview for ex: to page no 2 of the gridview

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the following:

- [Implement your code with the `using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)
- [Use parameterized SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Ensure your initial query returns a record and only one record (your loop will only capture the last encountered `username` and `usertype`)
- [Implement the `switch` statement and ensure proper handling of the `default` case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)
- Ensure your connection is open for your second SQL query
- If you are just re-throwing your exception, no need for a try/catch block.